# bpmn explorer @ wso2

Tags: wso2, bpmn, wso2-business-process

I need to customize the Search module of the BPMN Explorer integrated in wso2.

More exactly I want to be able to search using one of the task variables as search parameters.

I have looked in the git repository and came across https://github.com/wso2/carbon-business-process/blob/c6e60e57ab0de5d8de59041647f5cb9b7834d9c7/components/bpmn/org.wso2.carbon.bpmn.ui/src/main/resources/web/bpmn/instance_list_view.jsp

However this script is not in my BPS release (latest available downloaded already).

Could anyone please provide some pointers at least to how I could go about customizing the search function for bpmn explorer ?

Thanks!

Edit:
I managed to modify the gui (searchView.jag file )of the search function, but cannot add functionality for those new fields

Comment: what is the version that you are using? You can easily customized the code, rebuild the jar and use it

Comment: wso2bps version-3.5.1. But shouldn't I be able to find the instance_list_view.jsp as a .class file in my current release ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the necessary modifications (customize the seach function) to searchModel.jag file for the fields you added in searchView.jag. Please find it (searchModel.jag) under **`<BPS_HOME>`/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/bpmn-explorer/model** directory.

If you look at the **bpmn-explorer** folder you can see three sub-folders namely **controller**, **model** and **template**. Here controller folder includes set of .jag files which are used to check the request is secure or not, hold the session and build basic structure of the rendering pages. .jag files in model folder are used to implement the business logic say as an example invoke activiti rest api to get the process variables, process information, etc. The .jag files in the template folder are used to render the UI elements with appropriate results. Hope this resolves your issue.